# PhpStorm Codeception command line tool integration like with artisan?

Tags: phpstorm, codeception

Is it possible to integrate Codeception as a command line tool in PhpStorm?
Similar to how I can add artisan in `Tools->Command Line Tool Support` in order to get autocompletion for the artisan commands.

Comment: isn't there a plugin that does that ? (I think I have 2 of them installed)

Comment: Yes and No at the same time. Yes -- you can add it there ... but No -- it will not do what you are expecting to do as IDE does not support such tool (this way) directly. But yes, if you provide list of such commands and their parameters (XML file) then you will be able to use it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in PhpStorm `2017.2.1`.

In `File > Settings > Tools >Command Line Support` Click `Plus` button and choose `"Tool based on Symnfony Console"`

[image]

then choose `....\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept` for the script path

Regards